# rich:contextmenu appears under another component in Internet Explorer.

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Somewhat obscure problem. Only occures in Internet Explorer.
Perhaps someone familiar with this type of issue?
As visible in the screenshot, the Context menu appears under the h:panelgrid on the right.
[image: A Picture Example of the problem]

**Update** I tried to add style="z-index:1500;". Didn't help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a higher z-index value for the context menu.